# Averageif vs. Averageifs

Tags: excel, match, average, offset, evaluation

This formula returns what I need:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Hourly!$B$5:$B$100,$D$13,OFFSET(IF(H$15="DA",Hourly!$E$4,Hourly!$AD$4),1,MATCH(Summary!$B16,Hourly!$E$4:$AB$4,0)-1,105,1))

Evaluated:  =AVERAGEIF(Hourly!$B$5:$B$100,"t",Hourly!$I$5:$I$109)

= 31.12
```

This formula using =Averageifs does not.  I need to use =Averageifs because I am going to add on more criteria, but can't get the basic one to work first.  Please help.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(OFFSET(IF(H$15="DA",Hourly!$E$4,Hourly!$AD$4),1,MATCH(Summary!$B16,Hourly!$E$4:$AB$4,0)-1,105,1),Hourly!B5:$B$100,D13)

Evaluated:  =AVERAGEIFS(Hourly!$I$5:$I$109,Hourly!$B$5:$B$100,"t")

= #VALUE!
```

Comment: Try making the ranges the same size. either 5 to 100 or 5 to 109,

Comment: It worked!  I thought I was going insane.  I never thought to check that.  Thank you Scott.

Comment: Now look into non volatile methods of creating dynamic ranges.  OFFSET is  volatile.  It can almost always be replaced with INDEX.  Though the order of things is a little different.